# Parsing HTML files as PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing

Is this the correct way to parse html files as php?

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Saved in a .htaccess file in my root folder?

I am adding in a navigation bar that is called in via php and this would save renaming all my html files!

Thanks

Comment: When you tried it, did it work?

Comment: OK, now, some fresh programmer comes along which accidentally borks your .htaccess for some new feature. Result: all your code is plainly downloadable. Avoid this if you can, and if you must, please add it at a more safe point like apache/httpd.conf or vhost configuration.

Comment: @Wrikken so i shouldn't use this method at all?

Comment: Not unless you have a _very_ compelling reason to do it. And I cannot think of any atm, you might have one?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, if your webserver is running php as Apache module.

If your webserver is running PHP as CGI, use this instead:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Or, you could use this simple rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is running php as Apache. Is this a safe method to use?

Comment: Yes it is completely safe as long as you keep your source code in .php files and not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1\.php
```

Comment: OH. similar? So what? now i cant write the .htaccess in hebrew to make it different!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to parse HTML files as PHP so I added the code you mentioned on my .htaccess which is:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

It worked on my localhost as intended since I'm using WAMP but on my server, which is hosted in Drupion this does not work. My HTML files became downloadable.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127156/problem-with-htaccess-file-and-handlers) gave me an idea on how to fix the problem.

Basically, you need to know the "handler-name" your server is using to parse PHP. Then you can add similar code on your .htaccess.

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .html
FCGIWrapper /home/example/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .html
```