# HTML PHP if else statement

Tags: php, html

I have the following part of code inside my HTML body tag:

```
<?php if(1==2) { ?>

    <a class="demage" href="xxxx.html">demage</a>
    <a class="history" href="xxxx.html">history</a>

<?php } else { ?>

    <a class="Sign In" href="login_page.html">Sign In</a>
    <a class="Sign Up" href="register_page.html">Sign Up</a>

<?php } ?>
```

but it displays the 4 links in a row, not the last two as it is supposed to. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you sure PHP is running? Try view source on the page.

Comment: You sure the extension for this file is `.php`?

Comment: check your if condition passing correct values

Comment: it is showing Sign In and Sign Up link for me.. try checking `else if(1!=2){ links }`

Comment: This code is fine. Which webserver do you use ?

Comment: it is showing Sign In and Sign Up link for me too

Comment: @LozCheroneツ  No the file is a .html I cannot change the file extension so is there an other way inside a html file to do this?

Comment: Yes there is [another way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237044/parsing-html-files-as-php) but its not advised, why cant you change the extension? PHP needs to run through the PHP engine, else it wont get parsed.

Comment: use the javascript way.

Comment: @vaibhav whats the *javascript way*? interesting...

Comment: Ok i will change the extension and come back with an update Thanks

Comment: @vaibhav if the values are dynamic, the javascript way would not be possible, assuming he doesn't have PHP configured correctly.

Comment: Ok i change the extension and it worked. The problem was that i was running php code with .html extension! Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but instead of using curly brackets you can also make if-statements like this: `<?php if(something == true): ?> Some HTML <?php else: ?> Other HTML <?php endif; ?>`. It makes it easier to edit I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments, collective effort.

> By default PHP will only evaluate/parse files containing PHP with the extension
>   `.php`

Comment: Could you please clarify this; I think the statement is much too broad. I know what you're trying to indicate, however, this reads as if php is limited to reading only files and data that have a `.php` extension.

Comment: @l'L'l Yeah I suppose your right, if the OP's question is not read, it may seem broadish. Its community wiki so feel-free to word it better.

Answer (score 0):

[image: code]

I don't see any error in the code the code is running as expected. (See the image attached.)

May be there's some problem with your php.