# File extension .php

Tags: php, html, file-extension, server-side-scripting

I understand that the .php file extension is necessary for PHP parsing, but is it possible to work around this by putting the PHP code in a separate file and then using a .html file that includes it in a script tag?

Comment: The `.php` extension is not necessary. You can use an `.htaccess` to put additional rules, [as such](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6237056).

Comment: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` in an `.htaccess` file will enable your html files to be parsed for PHP scripts as well

Answer (score 2):

You can name a PHP script `a.blah`, which still runs:

```
php a.blah
```

As long as a.blah contains a valid PHP script.