# Using .htaccess to run PHP code within index.html

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to test executing php code within my index.html. To test this I'm using:

```
<?php
        phpinfo();
?>
```

If I change the file to .php it works fine, but I want it to execute as .html . I set up a .htaccess to do this but it's not working. This is my .htaccess:

```
<Files index.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html
</Files>
```

Both index.html and .htaccess are located in var/www/html. Why is the .html file not processing as .php when it has php code?

Comment: I have a need to keep the .html extension. I'm not asking whether this is good practice or not. @anubhava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the web server is not passing the `index.html` file thru the PHP interpreter is that the mime-type has not been associated with it.

You need to use the `AddHandler` directive to set it.

In order to associate the type you've added, it really depends on what your setup is. Various scenarios might be: php-fpm, mod_php, cgi.

An example using CGI is:

```
Action application/x-httpd-php5 "/path/to/php"
```

Bear in mind that this setting is usually not available on shared hosting. If you are using one, consider contacting the support helpdesk.

Consider having a look at this duplicate question: [Parsing HTML files as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237044/parsing-html-files-as-php)

I would suggest against adding a handler. You should rather rename the `index.html` file to `index.php`. If this is not picked by Apache, you can correct it using `DirectoryIndex index.php`.

I hope this helps.