# How do I process HTML files as PHP on AWS EC2 Linux?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I'm trying to move over to AWS EC2 and I've hit a sticking point. I've spent a full day trying every possible solution I could find on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, but to no avail.

I want to process .htm files as PHP files. Files ending in .php are processed just fine, but I can't get .htm files to be processed as PHP.

If I use this "AddHandler" syntax in .htaccess, nothing happens:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

"x-httpd-php" can literally be anything. It doesn't matter. Even this does nothing:

```
AddHandler application/its-a-fish .htm
```

Using this "AddType" syntax, on the other hand, always causes the file to be **downloaded** by the browser instead of parsed as code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Here again, what follows "application/" doesn't matter. All of these cause the file to be downloaded instead of processed:

```
AddType application/its-a-fish .htm
AddType application/x-http-php7 .htm
AddType application/x-http-php73 .htm
```

When the file is downloaded, the Content-Type in the Response header is whatever comes after "AddType" in .htaccess, e.g.:

```
Content-Type: application/x-http-php73
```

So maybe I just haven't found the "application" identifier my PHP is running under?

I've tried literally every code example I can find over a ~10-hour period (especially in these threads) but nothing has worked:

[Server not parsing .html as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295141/server-not-parsing-html-as-php)

[Parsing HTML files as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237044/parsing-html-files-as-php)

http://kb.cloudblue.com/en/115773

I suspect the reason it worked on all my previous servers and not on AWS is because PHP is running as FastCGI on AWS, not an Apache Handler, but I can't figure out how to make it work with FastCGI.

Here are the relevant packages I currently I have installed:

```
[root@ip-172-31-30-111 etc]# rpm -qa | egrep 'http|php'
libnghttp2-1.31.1-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
httpd-tools-2.4.39-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
mod_http2-1.14.1-1.amzn2.x86_64
php-pdo-7.3.6-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
generic-logos-httpd-18.0.0-4.amzn2.noarch
httpd-filesystem-2.4.39-1.amzn2.0.1.noarch
httpd-2.4.39-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
php-json-7.3.6-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-7.3.6-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
php-cli-7.3.6-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
php-common-7.3.6-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
php-fpm-7.3.6-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
```

Comment: Why can't you simply rename your PHP files to give them a .php suffix?

Comment: 1. Too many legacy files across too many sites to make it feasible.
2. It's an easy thing to do on every other platform I've used, so I'm convinced it's easy to do here as well if I could just figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

I *finally* figured this out, thanks primarily to this post:
https://talk.plesk.com/threads/cant-get-php-versions-to-serve-html-as-php.342045/page-2#post-854770

Here's what to do specifically on AWS EC2 Linux:

1. Add these lines to .htaccess, changing the "Files" section to specify the extensions you want to process as PHP:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
   <Files ~ (\.htm$)>
   SetHandler proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
   </Files>
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. Change the `security.limit_extensions` setting in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to allow the extensions you added in .htaccess (plus .php):

   ```
   security.limit_extensions = .php .htm
   ```
3. Restart the **php-fpm** service (restarting httpd will not force a reread of www.conf):

   ```
   service php-fpm restart
   ```

If you do #1 without doing #2, you will get an "Access denied" error. Step #2 is what fixes that.