# RewriteRule in htaccess returns the error Not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying the second way to run PHP code in HTMl file using a rule in .htaccess file as described by the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6237056/3208225

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

But when I try opening  my page e.g. `test.html` I receive

> Not Found

> The requested URL /test.html was not found on this server.

Why and how to resolve?

**UPDATED (from comments)**

I try both on localhost and on my shared hosting. htaccess and html files are in document root. BTW, the homepage (index.html) also returns *Not found*. In local machine the path is `D:/Server/vhosts/another`. And without this htaccess such virtual host works just fine. So there is no issue with its configuration.

Comment: Could you please do mention which sample link you are hitting and by which file you want to serve it in backend?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I follow by the link like `http://my-domain.com/test.html` and my PHP code is `<?php echo 'ok'; ?>`

Comment: The substitution portion of the RewriteRule arguments is not a regular expression, so do not "escape" characters like the dot in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure your htaccess is present along with your php files only. Also clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```bash
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

***Fix added by OP:*** Please note such rule is not execution of PHP code inside of HTML file, but just a redirecting from HTML file to PHP file, so the second file also must exist

Comment: @stckvrw, ok where are your htaccess and php files present? Kindly do mention all path details here.

Comment: @stckvrw, Do you have any other rules apart from these in your htaccess file? If yes then please do let me know and update your question also.

Comment: @stckvrw, Also mention path of htaccess and php files like: `/root/singh/test/.htaccess` etc etc

Comment: No, htaccess has these two rules only

Comment: @stckvrw, usually `not found` errors are path problems only. So kindly mention path of htaccess and php files like: `/root/singh/test/.htaccess etc`

Comment: @stckvrw, ok could you please do check if your virtual host entries are fine Eg: `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.ws
    DocumentRoot /home/me/Projects/website/build
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /home/me/Projects/website/build>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`?

Comment: @stckvrw, ok next thing we can check is, is your htaccess is enabled or not. Try putting a dummy line like: `----------------------` in your htaccess and save it and try to HIT anyink if you get 500 internal error then it means htsccess is enabled else it's not. Kindly do try it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yes, I get 500 error with the dummy line

Comment: Also I get 500 error when I add `RewriteBase D:/Server/vhosts/another` before RewriteRule

Comment: RewriteBase is supposed to be a URL path, not a file system path.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Oh, sorry, I found the reason. I just thought that if I create test.html file with PHP code, the code in such HTML file will be executed even if there is no test.php file, like on the fly. But I was wrong. So the reason was, there is no the test.php file

Comment: @stckvrw, ok cool good to know. Could you please do add further details to my answer, please edit it and I will approve it. So that future users will be benefited from this one, cheers.

Comment: @stckvrw, no please edit my answer, as answers are not supposed to be there in question. It will make difficult for future users to understand moreover its not encouraged to do so in Stack, thank you.

Comment: @stckvrw, yes, I mean whatever was the fix of the issue, as simple as that, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Ok, so do I understand it properly: the only way to execute PHP code inside of non-php file is the rule like `AddType application/x-httpd-lsphp .html` ? (only this one works in my shared hosting)

Comment: @stckvrw, I apologise here, I am not sure on this part `the only way to execute PHP code inside of non-php file is the rule like`. May be you could discus in new thread on this one, Sorry I am really not sure on this one, cheers.